# Any helps to Build Android App with Jenkins

Tags: android, ubuntu, jenkins, gradle, ssh

I have set up a Jenkins job for building my android project in the following steps:

1. SSHing to a ubuntu machine. I set it up with the SDK, java, gradle, etc.
2. Cloning my source code
3. Building the apk using "./gradlew assembleRelease"
4. Deploying it or emailing to me (A step after apk building, customizable)

However, the SSH tunnel closes to my remote machine during some steps in the android building process, like when the following module builds:
**:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevRelease**

I am looking for a way to keep the SSH tunnel ON so that the building command does not exist. I tried to run the command using **nohup** but still does the same.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I was able to go pass the ssh issue by making a small login machine changes as well, by adding 
Host* 
    ServerAliveInterval 600

However, following that I added --stacktrace flag and that would give me the following response:

```
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed) at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonC‌​lient.java:222)
```

It seems very odd because this error never appears when I build by directly logging onto the remote machine. It only happens when the build is triggered using Jenkins. Something seems to be killing the Gradle daemon because the JVM settings seem fine. Maybe the ssh detachment is still happening but at a different point in the process than the one I was earlier seeing.

Comment: Any progress so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening ssh connection to your ubuntu slave manually, then try increasing the connection timeout for the ssh server configurations ( `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ) by configuring the keep alive parameters as shown in example bellow:

```
# activates the keep alive verification (default is Yes)
# you could just set this to No but it would risk keeping ghost ssh sessions
TCPKeepAlive Yes
# sets the keep alive interval (in seconds) - this will send one keep alive per minute
ClientAliveInterval 60
# Sets the number of client alive messages which may be sent without sshd receiving any messages back
ClientAliveCountMax 10
```

This means that sshd will send one client alive per minute and will wait 10 minutes for a client response before closing ssh session.

Assuming that your whole jenkins build (checkout + installing stuff + gradle build) takes less then 10 minutes it should work fine.

Comment: I assume you meant these should go into /etc/ssh/sshd_config followed by a restart of the ssh service. Did that. Still same problem.

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevReleaseSSH: EXEC: completed after 146,514 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [server_hostname] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: @DipeshMittal could you add --stacktrace flag and update your question with it's contents?